# Update one parameter using Redux Tool kit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

When  I'm trying to update only one parameter of the following store other values automatically getting updated to their initial state. How can I prevent this?

My slice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  value: 0,
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState:{value:{name:"name",email:"",age:"",hobby:"",grade:""}},
  reducers: {
    login:(state,action)=>{
        state.value =action.payload;
    }
  },
})

export const { login } = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

Updating the value

```
if (value.topic=="cred") {

  console.log(value.username)
  dispatch(login({name:value.username}));
  console.log("Value dispatched",user.name)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just overwrite `value` you have to pass all the other properties as well, so you have 2 options to accomplish this.

## Option 1

You just pass `name` to the function and then change only that value.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
   name: "name",
   email: "",
   age: "",
   hobby: "",
   grade:""
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state,action) => {
        state.name = action.payload
    }
  },
})

export const { login } = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

And then you call it like this.

```js
if (value.topic=="cred") {

  console.log(value.username)
  dispatch(login(value.username));
  console.log("Value dispatched",user.name)
}
```

## Option 2

You're able to modify different field with the same reducer, even though I suggest creating more reducers.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
   value: {
      name: "name",
      email: "",
      age: "",
      hobby: "",
      grade:""
   }
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state,action) => {
        state.value = action.payload
    }
  },
})

export const { login } = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

And then you call it like this.

```js
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user)

if (value.topic=="cred") {

  console.log(value.username)
  dispatch(login({...user, name: value.username})); // You can modify also multiple value at once with {...user, name: value.username, hobby: "Something"}
  console.log("Value dispatched",user.name)
}
```

Comment: Hi  @remarcoble  `dispatch(login({...user, name: value.username}));` in here what is the use of `...user`

Comment: The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables. [If you want to read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#:~:text=The%20destructuring%20assignment%20syntax%20is%20a%20JavaScript%20expression%20that%20makes%20it%20possible%20to%20unpack%20values%20from%20arrays%2C%20or%20properties%20from%20objects%2C%20into%20distinct%20variables.)